# Disabled Rows' Data in Reactive Forms Can't Be Submitted

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

I have this unit_price inside of rows in reactive forms and it needs to be submitted and it also needs to be disabled because it is already set. Why i can't see the "unit_price" in the console.log after it is submitted? How can i fix this?
Here the link of the code [CODE LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch-2hkvfa?file=app/app.component.ts)

```
initGroup() {
    let rows = this.addForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
    rows.push(this.fb.group({
      ingredient_id: ['', Validators.required],
      unit_price: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }, Validators.required),
    }))
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to include all values regardless of disabled status, use `getRawValue` method instead of `value`

```
const Data = {
  ingredients: (this.addForm.get('rows') as FormArray).getRawValue(),
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch-rhxbow?file=app/app.component.ts)**